Why does the standard require only input iterators for std::distance, rather than forward iterators?
I was perplexed to see that the template parameter requirement for std::distance is a LegacyInputIterator rather than a LegacyForwardIterator.
Since input-only iterators don't have the multi-pass guarantee, the idea of "distance" between them doesn't have a reliable or useful meaning.
So the following code has meaning (even if it'a a little inefficient):
#include<iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list <int> l{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << std::distance(l.begin(), l.end()) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

But the following code does not:
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    auto z = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin.rdbuf());
    auto e = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>();
    std::cout << std::distance(z, e) << '\n';
}

std::distance may have counted the chars fed to it, but by the definition of istreambuf_iterator, those chars are gone, never to return.
This should be ill-formed or at least undefined behavior, but it is not.
(Rather than std::cin, I might open a file stream to a named pipe, which only gives me "sips" out of the firehose of data.)
Is there any committee-member discussion or proposal language for putting std::distance into the Standard that explains the choice of requirement?

It is probably not useful for input iterators, but it might be. Ex. it receives the rest of the input and at least tells you how much you missed. But it makes no sense for an output iterator at all, so I can understand why they would draw the line in the sand after input iterator, because at least is can practically compile and run. The standard comity isn't in the habit of restricting a feature on the basis that nobody was able to think of a use case.

@FrançoisAndrieux Which output iterator?

For example If you try to do the same thing with a std::ostreambuf_iterator it won't compile.

@FrançoisAndrieux But I was asking about forward iterators, not output iterators, which are in their own weird category..

My comment is trying to provide a potential reason why the requirement is for an input iterator instead of a forward iterator. Because while it might not seem useful at all, it is nonetheless valid code and makes sense algorithmically.

What's wrong with wanting to count the number of characters in an input stream, without caring what they are?  That's the entire function of the Unix wc -c utility, and it's extremely useful.

I guess the function is probably older than the standard. So there likely wouldn't be any discussion on this.

@FrançoisAndrieux  I'd prefer to see the proposal language that spells it out.   And as for  "restricting a feature on the basis that nobody was able to think of a use case for it", there is the famous example of operator[] for std::list.

@user17732522  I mean, we could probably go back to Stepanov and Lee if it was necessary.

@Spencer I don't expect there is any discussion on this topic to be found. It seems to me the requirement is simply defined such that those iterators that aren't compatible with the algorithm aren't allowed with it. Such a discussion might exist, but I don't see any reason to expect it to.

The operator[]  for std::list is a different scenario. In that case, it is a question of communicating the intent of the function. You can argue that such an operator for a sequence container might come with the expectation that it should be constant time. There is no question that operator[] for std::list would have use cases, the question is whether or not it might be considered misleading to provide it.

@FrançoisAndrieux  "it might be considered misleading to provide it" sums up my question about std::distance pretty well.  I think we'll have to agree to disagree on that point.

I thought about this just a few weeks ago and I came to the same conclusion as @NateEldredge. Why not allow it to be used with one-pass iterators? It can be used to count whatever it is the input iterator is iterating over.

@Spencer I guess what we disagree on is whether using std::distance with an input iterator could be misleading or not. To me it doesn't seem misleading, it just seems like the use case for it isn't obvious.

How would you say that being able to use std::distance in this way is misleading?  What could somebody possibly think that your std::distance(z,e) would do, that's different from what it actually does?

@NateEldredge It's misleading to assume that there is meaning to the result, similar to the idea that it's always important to have constant time access for operator[].  Why's that such a big deal?

@TedLyngmo But the only thing you're counting is what you just threw in the trash. I brought up the case of using std::distance on the named pipe.  It's counting the chars I get out of it (and then throw in the trash), but not necessarily all of them (other processes may be reading data from the pipe asynchronously).

But there is meaning to the result.  It tells you how many times z++ had to be executed in order to get to z == e.  Sure, you have discarded the data that was skipped over, but that may well be perfectly fine or desirable.  If I, the programmer, don't care what those bytes were, who is the Standard to tell me that I must preserve them?  In fact, as I said earlier, this seems like a potent argument in favor of allowing std::distance to be used this way; you've just implemented the very useful wc -c utility in basically two lines of code.

And just because this particular instance of the data is lost, doesn't mean that it was irreplaceable in the bigger picture.  Consider zcat foo.gz |wc -c to determine how large a file would be when uncompressed, e.g. to see if there is enough disk space for the uncompressed version.  I definitely don't want to preserve the output of zcat anywhere; I may not have anywhere to put it.  If I need it in the future, I'll just run zcat again.

The general rule is simple: preconditions should never be stronger than needed and postconditions should never be weaker.

You should not treat argument types as requirements on the input. They are more about what function requires itself. In other words, if you see signature like:
void func(const std::string& x);

you do not think, that this function requires constant string. You think that whatever the function does, it will need to apply only reading operation on its argument.
Similarly here. The difference between, LegacyInputIterator and LegacyForwardIterator is that the later supports multi pass algorithms. But you do not need it in order to calculate distance. It is a single pass algorithm.
If you put LegacyForwardIterator as an input parameter for std::distance you will disallow LegacyInputIterators as an input. Indeed it does not make a lot of senses to support such functionality, but it is there for free. And who knows, maybe somewhere there is a use case for that
